# How do I declare a variable as the same data type as the method returns in c#?

Tags: c#, methods

so I'm complete new not c#, and I ran out of ideas to try this. I've spent hours researching, but haven't found a solution.

My question is for the function `getUpcomingDates():` How do I declare the variable **`myDates`** as the same data type as the **`getAllDates`** method returns?

One of the ways I've tried is: `MyDate[] myDates = new getAllDates();` but I get a red line underneath getAllDates saying: 'it's a method but used as type.'

What's the correct way to do this?

```
[WebMethod]
private MyDate[] getAllDates()
{
    System.Collections.ArrayList myDates = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
    MyDate thisDate;


    thisDate = new MyDate(DateTime.Parse("9/1/2011"),
                          "Get classes ready", "Begin of fall semester");
    myDates.Add(thisDate);

    thisDate = new MyDate(DateTime.Parse("1/1/2011"),
                          "New Year", "Happy 2011!");
    myDates.Add(thisDate);

    thisDate = new MyDate(DateTime.Parse("12/16/2011"),
                          "BUS ADM 531 Final Exam", "See study guide on course Web pages");
    myDates.Add(thisDate);

    return (MyDate[])myDates.ToArray(typeof(MyDate));
}

[WebMethod]
private MyDate[] getUpcomingDates()
{
    MyDate[] myDates = new getAllDates();
    System.Collections.ArrayList upcomingDates = new System.Collections.ArrayList();


    foreach (MyDate thisDate in myDates)
    {
        if (thisDate.CalendarDate > DateTime.Now)
        {
            //date is upcoming, add to output list of dates
            upcomingDates.Add(thisDate);
        }
        else
        {
            //not an upcoming date, do not add to output list
        }

        return (MyDate[])upcomingDates.ToArray(typeof(MyDate));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To call a function, you just need (remove `new` from the line)

```
 MyDate[] myDates = getAllDates();
```

Comment: Thank you! I just realized that I added the return as the wrong spot, too.